# Retrieve all posted values in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, post, http-post

I am creating an ASP.NET application that allows the user to add form elements to a page within a form. When the page is posted (via the submit button) I need to loop through ALL the posted values in the form and get the values.

I can't check for specific values as I don't know how many there will be or what they will be called.

Could someone point me in the right direction of getting ALL posted values so I can loop through them?

p.s I was looking in Request.Form but couldn't see anything obvious to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) property returns a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) you can iterate over:

```
foreach (string name in Request.Form.AllKeys) {
    string value = Request.Form[name];
    // Do something with (name, value).
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just worked it out before checking back at this post but this is the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
    foreach (string key in Request.Form)
    {
        var value = Request.Form[key];
    }
```