# HashSet not works in HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, icomparer

I have a insert dto

```
public class InsertCircularStepDto
{
    public Guid CircularId { get; set; }

    public HashSet<CircularStepPrizeDto> Prizes { get; set; }
        = new(new CircularStepPrizeDtoComparer());
}

public class CircularStepPrizeDto
{
    public Guid ProductModelId { get; set; }

    public Guid ProductModelUnitId { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

With this comparer

```
public class CircularStepPrizeDtoComparer : IEqualityComparer<CircularStepPrizeDto>
{
    public bool Equals(CircularStepPrizeDto? x, CircularStepPrizeDto? y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return x.ProductModelId.Equals(y.ProductModelId) && x.ProductModelUnitId.Equals(y.ProductModelUnitId);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CircularStepPrizeDto obj)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(obj.ProductModelId, obj.ProductModelUnitId);
    }
}
```

I want to prevent duplicate records for prizes with same `ProductModelId` and `ProductModelUnitId`, when I use `[HttpGet]` it works correctly and if I send duplicate records for prize it gives me model state error:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromQuery] InsertCircularStepDto request)
{
    var result = await _circularStepFacade.InsertCircularStepService.ExecuteAsync(request);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

But when I use `[HttpPost]` it doesn't works and it not prevent duplicate records of prizes with same `ProductModelId` and `ProductModelUnitId`:

```
// Not works
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] InsertCircularStepDto request)
{
    var result = await _circularStepFacade.InsertCircularStepService.ExecuteAsync(request);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Why my comparer works in `[HttpGet]` and it doesn't work in `[HttpPost]`, I asked chat GPT And gives me this code and it's works in `[HttpPost]` but it doesn't return model state error, if I send duplicate records for prizes, it just remove duplicate records not return model state error:

```
public class InsertCircularStepDto
{
    public Guid CircularId { get; set; }

    private HashSet<CircularStepPrizeDto> _prizes = new(new CircularStepPrizeDtoComparer());

    public List<CircularStepPrizeDto> Prizes
    {
        get => _prizes.ToList();
        set => _prizes = new HashSet<CircularStepPrizeDto>(value, new CircularStepPrizeDtoComparer());
    }
}
```

but I want to know why `HashSet<CircularStepPrizeDto>` not works for me in `[HttpPost]` ?

Comment: You can't rely on Hashcode to be unique.  Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425142/what-is-hashcode-used-for-is-it-unique  and scroll down to the accepted answer and read the text from Microsoft.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith thanks, but why it's works in ```[HttpGet]``` and only not works in ```[HttpPost]```

Comment: @MiladAhmadi Please [edit] your question to include the model state errors you get when you use the `GET` request. Also, for debugging purposes, add the fully received query string and form data body to your question for both your `GET` and `POST` requests. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428149/retrieve-all-posted-values-in-asp-net and https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.8.1 on how to do this. There shouldn't be any model state errors at all generated when you have "duplicates" in your `Prizes` property.

Comment: Side note: `if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;` should not be there. If the class is subclassed (derived) correctly then just using `.Equals` should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a code smell, the real solution is to decouple the class that implements IEqualityComparer out of the DTO.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] InsertCircularStepDto request)
{
    var seen = new HashSet<CircularStepPrizeDto>(new CircularStepPrizeDtoComparer());

    foreach (var prize in request.Prizes)
    {
        if (!seen.Add(prize))
        {
        }
    }    
}
```

> why it's works in [HttpGet] and only not works in [HttpPost]

This is how the model binding works the GET the model binding occurs through the query string, and POST is via the the body - so it deserilized as JSON data, it relates to the fact that its creates the collection first without considering the comparer.

If you still want to keep your solution without de-coupling the comperare from the DTO you can modify the model binding de-serilization or use a custom comparer logic

Comment: I wrote a custom comparer (It' exists in question), it doesn't execute in ```[HttPost]``` requests

Comment: something like this: `public List<CircularStepPrizeDto> Prizes { get => _prizes.ToList(); set { var tempSet = new HashSet<CircularStepPrizeDto>(value, new CircularStepPrizeDtoComparer());  } _prizes = tempSet; } }` ?